# Why Deferred is not working when resolve is inside a function

Tags: jquery

This code works http://jsfiddle.net/neerajdotname/k2Q9b/

But this code does not work http://jsfiddle.net/neerajdotname/k2Q9b/1/

Why?

And what's the fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the paranthesis at the end of dfd.resolve:

```
 function func(){dfd.resolve;};
```

Should be:

```
 function func(){dfd.resolve();};
```

As it is now you are simply stating the name of the function, not actually calling it.